# How do I lock the screen in x11

Tags: c, linux, x11

I am trying to write a tiny x11 screen locker program (something like i3lock) in c. When the program is run it spawns a full screen window. I want this window to intercept all keyboard input preventing the user from leaving until they have entered the password. How would I go about intercepting the keyboard input and preventing the user from leaving?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Look at i3lock sources, how does it do this?

Comment: One way is with a *modal* window.  See [X11 modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779316/x11-modal-dialog) to get started.

Comment: You should find out how xscreensaver works because it already does this. Or i3lock as you mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If I understand it correctly a modal dialog only prevents you from using its parent window. I'll go have a look at i3lock and xscreensaver source. I thought I might get lucky and be able to avoid having to take a look at its source. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Perhaps.  It's been a long time since I've done direct X11 programming.  But I do remember finding out that mapping a modal window in a way where it wasn't visible because I botched the code was a great way to totally lock out all input.  Window: "I get all input!"  Manager: "You're not visible - you get no input!"

Comment: Suggestion: change the title to something like "how do I lock the screen in x11?". It's better keywords.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah your right.

Comment: If you're writing a screen locker, there are security considerations you should be aware of. The author of xscreensaver discusses them [here](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/toolkits.html).

Comment: Interesting thanks @Ray